# Make a cell empty instead of zero if its formula fails in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Lets say I have 3 cells with the following contents:

```
A1 = "" (Empty)
B1 = "" (Empty)
C1 = PRODUCT(A1, B1)
```

I assumed C1 would be empty given that A1 and B1 are empty. However, C1 displays 0 instead. What I want to do is make C1 empty if any/both of A1 and B1 is/are empty. Is there a way to do this? I read somewhere that spreadsheets treat empty cells as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `If()`:

```
=IF(OR(A1="",B1=""),"",PRODUCT(A1,B1))
```

(Or use `AND()` if *both* need to be blank to return `""`.)

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like:

```
=IF(LEN(A1&B1), PRODUCT(A1, B1), )
```

[image: 0]